# Cannot read property 'map' of null, regex matching groups

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

This snip of code with match and map ...

```
.match(/5px">(.*?)<\/b>/g).map(function(val){return val.replace(/<\/?b>/g,'').replace(/5px">/g,'').trim();});
```

... works to create this array ...
["First text in array", "Second text in array"]

... when matching to this text string ...

```
5px">First text in array </b> random text 5px"> Second text in array </b>
```

In context of a larger script, I get Cannot read property 'map' of null.  Is there another approach to achieve the same resulting array?  matchAll or match with different arguments?

I am working in Apps Script attempting to parse a gmail summary message into multiple spreadsheet rows.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: `const results = match(/5px">(.*?)<\/b>/g); if (results) { ... }`

Comment: The reason for the error is that the string does not have matches for the regex. You should define what should happen in that case. You could do `(str.match(/5px">(.*?)<\/b>/g)??[]).map(......`.

Comment: Thank you for comments and answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get the captured value from your matches:

```js
const string = '5px">First text in array </b> random text 5px"> Second text in array </b>'
console.log(
   Array.from(string.matchAll(/5px">(.*?)<\/b>/g), z => z[1].trim())
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to matchAll between these 2 strings "* " and "* " (asterisk followed by space) using this same snip of code?  I cannot seem to get the syntax right since * has meaning in regex.

Comment: @JeffSmith, Yes, `string.matchAll(/\* (.*?)\* /gs)`

Comment: Thanks @Ryszard, works great. To remove the * so they are not included in the resulting array, I am trying string.matchAll(/* (.*?)* /gs).replace('*','') which does not work. I assume I need to use a more sophisticated regex to handle the replace?

Comment: @JeffSmith Sorry, I do not get it. If you provide an example text and required output, I can help more. Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer.